# What is the 'story' of Where's Wally?

Tags: books, wheres-wally

Is there any story behind Where's Wally (Waldo)? books? There was a TV show, as described on wikipedia:

> Wally and his dog Woof travel to distant lands, solving mysteries and lending a helping hand wherever they could. With the help of his magic walking stick, Wally could travel through space and time or travel to far off magical lands. Often sent by Wizard Whitebeard to help solve a puzzle, or mysteries, "Where's Wally" was a 1/2 hour puzzle of clues and riddles.

But did the original books have a set plot or story?

Comment: If you want the "story" behind the original book, here it is: http://waldo.wikia.com/wiki/Where%27s_Waldo%3F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the original book, the "Story" of Where's Waldo is found on the Where's Waldo Wiki:
[Waldo Origin](http://waldo.wikia.com/wiki/Where%27s_Waldo?)

Here's the "story" as per that wiki-page:

> Where's Waldo? introduces readers to Waldo, a distinctively dressed man, as he sets off on "a world-wide hike". Waldo travels to everyday places – such as the beach, the ski slopes and the zoo. The book features 12 detailed 2-page illustrated spreads of the different locations. Somewhere amid the crowded scene is Waldo and readers are asked to scour the detailed illustrations to locate the lost traveler. Each scene is accompanied by a postcard to the reader from Waldo, who introduces the scene and comments on his travels.
>
> Waldo sets out on his journey equipped with 12 items to help him on his travels. He carries a walking stick, kettle, mallet, cup, backpack, sleeping bag, binoculars, camera, snorkel, belt, bag and shovel. As Waldo journeys from location to location he loses one of these item, and asks the reader to locate the object left behind in each scene as well.

Comment: So they are nothing like the TV series then...I'm sure I've seen books where he's traveled in time and such like?

Comment: In some of the books he has, there have been many books. Refer to [Where's Waldo Wikia](http://waldo.wikia.com/wiki/Waldo_Wiki)